# error at root position 1, line 1

Tags: vb.net, xmlreader

I am using the following snippet to get the xml content but get the above mentioned error. In a webbrowser like chrome I get a nice formatted result. Other requests on the same site go well but this one gives me an error.

```
   Dim sWebUrlXml As String = "http://publications.elia.be/Publications/Publications/InternetImbalance.v1.svc/GetImbalanceMeasuresByTime"
   Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(sWebUrlXml)
        Do While (reader.Read())
....
....
```

http://publications.elia.be/Publications/Publications/InternetImbalance.v1.svc/GetImbalanceMeasuresByTime

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on but if you download the data using `Dim client As New WebClient()` and then `Dim s As String = client.DownloadString(uri)` it starts with Time rather than the top node.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Jim88909. True; I've done it that way also. I am now going to use the result of a client.DownloadString and analyze it with keywords and such.